# C# How to randomize the number on 10 buttons (0 - 9) without duplicates

Tags: c#, random, unique

1.This is what i've got this so far

2.Its suppposed to randomize the numbers on the buttons when it starts. But it still generates duplicates (and i dont want duplicates).

3. I use Visual studio 2012 C# for this
4. Its only supposed to do it once i startup the program. So its a one time randomize

   ```
               Random rand = new Random();
               int RandomOne = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomTwo = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomThree = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomFour = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomFive = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomSix = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomSeven = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomEight = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomNine = rand.Next(0, 10);
               int RandomZero = rand.Next(0, 10);

               btnOneNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomOne);


               if ((RandomTwo == RandomOne) || (RandomTwo == RandomNine) || (RandomTwo == RandomThree) || (RandomTwo == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomTwo == RandomFive) || (RandomTwo == RandomSix) || (RandomTwo == RandomSeven) || (RandomTwo == RandomEight) || (RandomTwo == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomTwo = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else 
               {
                   btnTwoNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomTwo);
               }


               if ((RandomThree == RandomOne) || (RandomThree == RandomTwo) || (RandomThree == RandomNine) || (RandomThree == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomThree == RandomFive) || (RandomThree == RandomSix) || (RandomThree == RandomSeven) || (RandomThree == RandomEight) || (RandomThree == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomThree = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnThreeNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomThree);
               }


               if ((RandomFour == RandomOne) || (RandomFour == RandomTwo) || (RandomFour == RandomThree) || (RandomFour == RandomNine)
                   || (RandomFour == RandomFive) || (RandomFour == RandomSix) || (RandomFour == RandomSeven) || (RandomFour == RandomEight) || (RandomFour == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomFour = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnFourNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomFour);
               }


               if ((RandomFive == RandomOne) || (RandomFive == RandomTwo) || (RandomFive == RandomThree) || (RandomFive == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomFive == RandomNine) || (RandomFive == RandomSix) || (RandomFive == RandomSeven) || (RandomFive == RandomEight) || (RandomFive == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomFive = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnFiveNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomFive);
               }


               if ((RandomSix == RandomOne) || (RandomSix == RandomTwo) || (RandomSix == RandomThree) || (RandomSix == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomSix == RandomFive) || (RandomSix == RandomNine) || (RandomSix == RandomSeven) || (RandomSix == RandomEight) || (RandomSix == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomSix = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnSixNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomSix);
               }


               if ((RandomSeven == RandomOne) || (RandomSeven == RandomTwo) || (RandomSeven == RandomThree) || (RandomSeven == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomSeven == RandomFive) || (RandomSeven == RandomSix) || (RandomSeven == RandomNine) || (RandomSeven == RandomEight) || (RandomSeven == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomSeven = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnSevenNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomSeven);
               }


               if ((RandomEight == RandomOne) || (RandomEight == RandomTwo) || (RandomEight == RandomThree) || (RandomEight == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomEight == RandomFive) || (RandomEight == RandomSix) || (RandomEight == RandomSeven) || (RandomEight == RandomNine) || (RandomEight == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomEight = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnEightNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomEight);
               }


               if ((RandomNine == RandomOne) || (RandomNine == RandomTwo) || (RandomNine == RandomThree) || (RandomNine == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomNine == RandomFive) || (RandomNine == RandomSix) || (RandomNine == RandomSeven) || (RandomNine == RandomEight) || (RandomNine == RandomZero))
               {
                   RandomNine = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else 
               {
                   btnNineNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomNine);
               }


               if ((RandomZero == RandomOne) || (RandomZero == RandomTwo) || (RandomZero == RandomThree) || (RandomZero == RandomFour)
                   || (RandomZero == RandomFive) || (RandomZero == RandomSix) || (RandomZero == RandomSeven) || (RandomZero == RandomEight) || (RandomZero == RandomNine))
               {
                   RandomZero = rand.Next(0, 10);
               }
               else
               {
                   btnZeroNgra.Text = Convert.ToString(RandomZero);
               }
   ```

Comment: One solution could be to add the numbers(0-9) to a list, shuffle and select a random index, remove element at the index. repeat. EDIT: perhaps select the next index - not a random index after the shuffle.

Comment: You need to do this in a while loop and not a single if-statement. If you check it once and then change it, it may get the same value like another also has.

Comment: @Achilles That's of course a way better solution.

Comment: Can you give me an example code of how im supposed to do so. Im still a student and need to learn

Comment: @NoahDeGraaff If you need to learn I suggest you go try it out. Copy code from SO doesn't teach you anything.

Answer (score 0):

The approach for this case should be to create ten numbers in a list and then take one by one to avoid duplication, something like the following:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

private int getNumber(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(0, nums.Count);
    int num = nums[index];
    nums.RemoveAt(index);
    return num;
}
```

You might need to be careful though, it cannot be called more than 10 times... You might want to create little error handler like:

```
private int getNumber(){
    if(nums.Count >= 0)
        return -1; //means not available
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(0, nums.Count);
    int num = nums[index];
    nums.RemoveAt(index);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using `Enumerable.Range(0, 9)` to generate the list of numbers. That way you can make it dynamic.

Comment: @DavidG good idea... since the second element is `count` I think I should go with `0,10` though

Comment: I think `.ToList()` looks better, but this works too :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try with HashSet:

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
Random randomizer = new Random();

while (numbers.Count < 10)
{
   numbers.Add(randomizer.Next(0, 10));
}
```

HashSet would make sure that all the values are unique.

Comment: It would also throw an exception and not give you all the numbers from 0-9 without running it potentially for a very long time (from a probabilistic standpoint)

Comment: It does not throw an exception

Comment: OK, yes it won't throw an exception but the loop will run dozens of unnecessary times.

Comment: For info, I have tested this a few times. Sometimes it takes less than 20 loops, sometimes it takes over 100.